# What does NOT NULL constraint failed: generalpage_userregister.user_id mean and how is the issue resolved in my case?

Tags: python, django, error-handling, custom-model-binder

I'm trying to create a website using Django but have an issue I've been struggling with for a few hours. Can someone explain why I recieve:

NOT NULL constraint failed: generalpage_userregister.user_id

error and how to resolve this issue?

I suspect it has something to do with the pk but I can't get my head around this.

I'm trying to create a custom model and when I try to create a superuser, I get the error mentioned above.

my view is:

````
    page = "create-account"
    form = UserRegisterForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userRegister = form.save(commit=False)
            userRegister.user = request.user(id=pk)
            #user.username = user.username.lower()
            userRegister.save()
            
            #login(request, userRegister)
            return redirect("generalpage:home-page")
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
                        
    context = {"form": form, "page": page}
    return render(request, "generalpage/create_account.html", context) ```

My urls are:

``` from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "generalpage"

urlpatterns = [
    path("hem/", views.home, name="home-page"),
    
    path("registrering/", views.registerprofile, name="register-page"),
    
    path("logga-in/", views.loginpage, name="login-page"),
    path("logga-ut", views.logoutuser, name="logoutuser"),
     
    path("skapa-annons/", views.createroom, name="createroom-page"),
    path("skapa-konto/<str:pk>/", views.createaccount, name="createaccount-page"),
    
    path("radera-rum/", views.deleteroom, name="deleteroom"),
    path("uppdatera-rum/", views.updateroom, name="updateroom"), 
] ```

the models is:

``` from datetime import datetime
import email
from email import message
from email.policy import default
from enum import unique
from pyexpat import model
from wsgiref.validate import validator
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, User, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from . managers import UserRegisterManager
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class UserRegister(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(_("Användarnamn"), max_length=100, null=True, unique=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
    
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, default="avatar.svg")
    
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' # defines the unique identifier for the User model
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"] # A list of the field names that will be prompted for when creating a user via the createsuperuser management command
    
    objects = UserRegisterManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username ```

The form is:

``` from dataclasses import field, fields
from django import forms 
from .models import User, UserInfo, Room, UserRegister
from generalpage import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# User register account page
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRegister
        exclude = ["password", "last_login"]
        #fields = "__all__" ```

The user manager that I've created is:

``` from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class UserRegisterManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where username is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('Du måste ange ett användarnamn'))
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Du måste ange ett email'))
        if not password:
            raise ValueError(_('Du måste ange ett lösenord'))
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given username and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superanvändare måste ha is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superanvändare måste ha is_superuser=True.'))
        
        return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
````

My settings is:

```
Django settings for sx_site project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-c__5bvtpvm)k71%n=+@&y4&2#n883)xj=!77ujo5-4krdeuouk'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'generalpage.apps.GeneralpageConfig',
    'profilesettings.apps.ProfilSettingsConfig',
    'trainingApp.apps.TrainingappConfig',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sx_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sx_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
    ]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'generalpage.UserRegister'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `UserRegister` object without specifying `user` field. It's not possible, because you have:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here you don't exclude `user` field:

```
model = UserRegister
exclude = ["password", "last_login"]
```

Just add `"user"` to exclude and it should be ok.

Comment: Hello! 
I still recieve the same error. Do you know that the error means? I don't even understand it in order to figure out a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @AbbasJafari I explained it in the answer. It means that you are trying to create `UserRegister` object without specifying `user` field. Now I see, that you have done that: `userRegister.user = request.user(id=pk)` - why do you try use that `(id=pk)`? `request.user` is already `User` object, you cannot filter it (which actually turns it to `None`). Delete parenthesis, there might be real reason it does not find user.